# Being cache efficient with data, mainly arrays

Tags: c++, performance, caching, memory

I have recently started to look into being cache efficient by trying to avoid cache misses in c++. So far I have taken away the following:

- Try and avoid linked lists objects where possible when processing. Instead use them to point to contiguous data that you can store in cache and perform operations on.
- Be careful of holding state in classes as it makes the above potentially more difficult.
- Use structs when allocating on the heap, as this helps in localising data.
- Try and use 1D arrays when possible for lists of data.

So my question is broken into two parts:

- Is the above correct? Have I made any fundamental misunderstandings?
- When dealing with 2D arrays I have seen other users recommend the use of Hilbert curves. I do not understand how this provides a speed increase over using division and modulus operators on an index to simulate a 2D array as that is surely less instructions which is good for speed and instruction cache usage?

Thanks for reading.

P.S. I do not have a CompSci background therefore, if you notice anything that I have said that is incorrect I would appreciate it if you could alert me so that I can read around that topic.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Use structs as this helps in localising data.'?

Comment: @SergeyA My understanding of what I have read is that a possible use of a struct is to help keep data contiguous in memory. Therefore, it can be used to bunch up different variables that will require to be operated on at the same time, to avoid cache misses.

Comment: **what** data? **what** variables? variables which are declared one after another will always be adjacent to each other, struct or no struct.

Comment: Does this hold true on heap allocation as well?

Comment: I think this is looking for trouble. Are cache misses a real problem in your case? Do you need the performance gain? I would not go deeper in this area unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @John, now are are getting somewhere. You see, this is what I was trying to make you think about. Yes, heap allocations. But! You know what's better than heap allocations for struct? No heap allocations.

Comment: @marom Yes the computations are on large datasets and time performance is a large factor.

Comment: @SergeyA I completely agree and understand that. However, the size of these variables is only known during execution. So with my knowledge I feel like heap allocation is what I am left with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is flawed for at least one reason: you are willing to sacrifice everything to avoid cache misses. How do you know if that (cache misses) is the major performance factor in your code?

For example, there are **MANY** cases where the use of linked list is better that a contiguous array, specifically - where you frequently insert / delete items. You would pay greatly for compacting or expanding an array.

So the answer to your first question is: yes, you will improve the data locality using those four principals. But - at the cost, probably greater than the savings.

For the second question, I suggest you read about [Hilbert curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve). You don't need them if you are processing your 2D array in order, row-by-row. They will help a lot (with data locality) if you process some area of your 2D array, because the distance between elements in the same column/different rows is much smaller that way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The first question I am asking is more to do with theory as that is something I lack in this space. The second question has to do with what I am working on currently. Therefore, for example:

If I had a 2D image represented in a 1D array through the use of a Hilbert curve and wanted to perform localised (lets say each quadrant) 2D FFTs this would therefore be faster?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the pattern of the memory access that FFT uses. You may need to measure, or do some research.